# How to write a nested loop to iterate over a range of dates with each date having a 24 hour range of time?

Tags: javascript, database, date

my database is returning a start date and an end date .Also , it returns a start time and and end time. i want to extract one time slot in one day, using javascript nested loop. I know how to iterate over the date but cant get a solution for the time.
2014-04-29 10:00:00 is the return format for the data.

Comment: `i want to extract one time slot in one day` what does that mean?

Comment: You havn't taken the help tour. It is under help at the top RHS of the page.

Comment: Do you want this in pure JS, or using deps? If deps, I suggest looking at [moment](http://momentjs.com).

Comment: Javascript Date objects have a *time value* that represents an instant in time, so they inherently have a date and time part. "2014-04-29 10:00:00" is not consistent with any standard that I'm aware of, though it is similar to ISO 8601. Should it be treated as UTC or "local"?